# Is Certificates are required for STARTTLS connection on LDAP

Tags: ldap, starttls, pam-ldap, mod-auth-ldap, ldapmodule

My LDAP server's ldap.conf file

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=coretesting,dc=com
URI     ldap://ldap.coretesting.com #ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/ssl/certs/
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem    
TLS_CERT /etc/ssl/certs/slapd01.pem
TLS_KEY /etc/ssl/private/slapd01_key.pem
#TLS_CRLCHECK all
#TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN 3
```

Whenever my **client tries to connect with the server *first time alone* ldap_start_tls_s fails**.

Error code **ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)**

The **second time onwards it is working fine**.

I know that ***TLS_REQCERT demand* data on *ldap.conf* file can *resolve* this error**.

When we try to use a **secured connection there is *no meaning of providing other than demand* option**.

If any experts know the root cause or solution please let me know.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: AFAIK `TLS_REQCERT` is directive in client config, not server

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov,

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, As per my understating to avoid unauthenticated users and to improve security on server side we are providing demand option on server. If we provide other than demand option whoever know user name and server they can also try to connect with server right. Could you please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: kindly refer belwo link and refer to following section https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html16.2.1.9. TLSVerifyClient { never | allow | try | demand }

Comment: Please check https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin21/tls.html The directive for server is `TLSVerifyClient`

Comment: Now i got your point.  TLSVerifyClient  is configuration on server side and TLS_REQCERT  is client side is your point right. In my case both I had configured as demand only. Very first time alone my client couldn't able to connect with server. Second time onwards able to connect successfully.